# VBA-Wedriver-Selenium-Xpath - Modify Class Value - Click Button -Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am opening a website using Chrome Webdriver.
I wanted to Modify value to 12 instead of 10 in a box

HTML Code

```html
<div class="input-currency input-colors">
    <input type="tel" autocomplete="off" class="input-currency__input" data-test="deal-amount-input" maxlength="9" value="10" />
    <div class="input-currency__values"><span class="input-currency__value">10</span>&nbsp;<span class="input-currency__sign psign">Đ</span></div>
</div>
```

My Codes

```
Dim Bot As WebDriver
Dim posts As WebElements, post As WebElement
Set Bot = New WebDriver
Bot.Start "chrome"
Bot.Get "https://olymptrade.com/platform#"

Bot.FindElementsByXPath("//span[contains(@class,'input-currency__value')]").Values = 12
Bot.FindElementByClass("input-currency input-colors").Text
```

Also there is a button of Buy with Green color, I wanted to click on it.

HTML Code

```html
<div class="deal-buttons__item deal-buttons__item_up">
    <button data-test="deal-button-up" class="deal-buttons__button deal-buttons__button_up">
        <span>
            <span class="deal-buttons__text">80%</span>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#FFF" fill-opacity="0.5" class="deal-buttons__svg deal-buttons__svg_arrow">
                <path d="M14.6 8l-8.3 8.3a1 1 0 0 0 1.4 1.4L16 9.4V17a1 1 0 0 0 2 0V7a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 1 0 0 2h7.6z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

My Code

```
Bot.FindElementsByXPath("//span[contains(@class,'deal-buttons__text ')]").Click
Bot.FindElementsByXPath("//button[contains(@class,'deal-buttons__button deal- buttons__button_up')]").Click
```

I wanted to change the value and Click on buy button using selenium webdriver

provide me hint on my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindElements` returns a collection. You want a single webElement i.e. a single item of that collection. You need to determine the appropriate index and use that or, if want first match, use methods, for example as shown below, which are singular.

```
Bot.FindElementByCss(".input-currency input").SendKeys "12"   'though you may need to clear element first
```

If need to clear first then:

```
With Bot.FindElementByCss(".input-currency input")
    .Clear
    .SendKeys "12" 
End With
```

The button html is not provided by you but again you need singular method or index. Assuming want first, and xpath correct:

```
Bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(@class,'deal-buttons__text ')]").Click
```